# WebTestClient does not post object

Tags: unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, spring-webflux

I am trying to perform simple test of reading method. I am trying to work with reactive approach so to test whole context I am using WebTestClient. Although post method seems to work correctly reading operation is not working. But why? Isn't it should be saved to embedded mongo database?
Do I need to wait for it somehow if this is reactive?

**Exception is thrown definitely in service because I am seeing**

**com.geborskimateusz.util.exceptions.NotFoundException: No product found for productId: 1**

This is how test looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, properties = {"spring.data.mongodb.port: 0"})
public class MovieServiceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Autowired
    MovieService movieService;

    @Test
    public void getMovie() {
        Integer given = 1;

        postAndVerify(given, HttpStatus.OK);

        Movie movie = movieService.getMovie(given); **fails here**
        assertNotNull(movie);

        getAndVerify(given, HttpStatus.OK);

    }

    private WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec postAndVerify(Integer id, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
        Movie movie = Movie.builder()
                .movieId(id)
                .title("Title for movie " + id)
                .genre("Genre for movie " + id)
                .address("Address for movie " + id)
                .build();

        return webTestClient.post()
                .uri("/movie")
                .body(Mono.just(movie), Movie.class)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(httpStatus)
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBody();
    }

    private WebTestClient.BodyContentSpec getAndVerify(Integer id, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
                return webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/movie/" + id)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isEqualTo(httpStatus)
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .expectBody()
                .jsonPath("$.movieId").isEqualTo(id)
                .jsonPath("$.genre").isNotEmpty()
                .jsonPath("$.title").isNotEmpty()
                .jsonPath("$.address").isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Service and repository are very simple implementations:

**Service:**

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class BaseMovieService implements MovieService {

    private final ServiceUtil serviceUtil;
    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    private final MovieMapper movieMapper = MovieMapper.INSTANCE;

    @Autowired
    public BaseMovieService(ServiceUtil serviceUtil, MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        this.serviceUtil = serviceUtil;
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }


    @Override
    public Movie getMovie(Integer movieId) {

        if (movieId < 1) throw new InvalidInputException("Invalid productId: " + movieId);

        MovieEntity movieEntity = movieRepository.findMovieById(movieId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("No product found for productId: " + movieId));

        Movie movie = movieMapper.entityToApi(movieEntity);
        movie.setAddress(serviceUtil.getServiceAddress());

        log.debug("/movie return the found movie for movieId={}", movieId);

        return movie;
    }

    @Override
    public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {

        try {

            MovieEntity movieEntity = movieMapper.apiToEntity(movie);
            MovieEntity saved =  movieRepository.save(movieEntity);

            log.debug("createMovie: entity created for movieId: {}", movie.getMovieId());
            return movieMapper.entityToApi(saved);
        }catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("Duplicate key for movieId: " +movie.getMovieId());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteMovie(Integer movieId) {

    }
}
```

**And repo:**

```
public interface MovieRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MovieEntity, String> {
    Optional<MovieEntity> findMovieById(Integer movieId);
}
```

This is however strange because I am sure that repo work fine, all tests below are passing:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DataMongoTest
public class MovieRepositoryTest {

    public static final int BASE_MOVIE_ID = 1;
    @Autowired
    MovieRepository movieRepository;

    MovieEntity savedMovieEntity;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        movieRepository.deleteAll();

        MovieEntity movieEntity = MovieEntity
                .builder()
                .movieId(BASE_MOVIE_ID)
                .title("Raise of Jedi")
                .address("123.321.54x24")
                .genre("Sci-Fi")
                .build();

        savedMovieEntity = movieRepository.save(movieEntity);

        assertEqualsMovie(movieEntity, savedMovieEntity);
    }

    @Test
    void create() {
        MovieEntity movieEntity = MovieEntity
                .builder()
                .movieId(2)
                .title("Fall of Jedi")
                .address("125.721.54x24")
                .genre("Sci-Fi")
                .build();

        MovieEntity saved = movieRepository.save(movieEntity);

        assertEqualsMovie(movieEntity, saved);
        assertEquals(2, movieRepository.count());
    }

    @Test
    void update() {
        String givenTitle = "Updated Title";

        savedMovieEntity.setTitle(givenTitle);

        MovieEntity updated = movieRepository.save(savedMovieEntity);

        assertEquals(givenTitle, updated.getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    void findById() {
        Optional<MovieEntity> optionalMovieEntity = movieRepository.findById(savedMovieEntity.getId());

        assertTrue(optionalMovieEntity.isPresent());

        MovieEntity movieEntity = optionalMovieEntity.get();

        assertEqualsMovie(savedMovieEntity, movieEntity);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldPerformOptimisticLocking() {
        String concurrentM1actionData = "Concurrent action data performed on M1";
        String concurrentM2actionData = "Concurrent action data performed on M2";

        MovieEntity m1 = movieRepository.findById(savedMovieEntity.getId()).get();
        MovieEntity m2 = movieRepository.findById(savedMovieEntity.getId()).get();

        m1.setTitle(concurrentM1actionData);

        // by updating Entity its version should be updated
        movieRepository.save(m1);

        // should fail because of version mismatch
        try {
            m2.setTitle(concurrentM2actionData);
            movieRepository.save(m2);
            fail("Expected an OptimisticLockingFailureException");
        } catch (OptimisticLockingFailureException e) {
            System.out.println("shouldPerformOptimisticLocking() -> catch OptimisticLockingFailureException");
        }

        //check current version and state
        MovieEntity updatedMovieEntity = movieRepository.findById(savedMovieEntity.getId()).get();
        assertEquals(1, (int) updatedMovieEntity.getVersion());
        assertEquals(concurrentM1actionData, updatedMovieEntity.getTitle());
    }

    @Test
    void delete() {
        movieRepository.delete(savedMovieEntity);
        assertEquals(0, movieRepository.count());
    }

    @Test
    void duplicateMovieError() {
        MovieEntity duplicate = MovieEntity.builder().build();
        duplicate.setId(savedMovieEntity.getId());

        assertThrows(DuplicateKeyException.class, () -> movieRepository.save(duplicate));
    }

    @Test
    void paging() {

        bulkSaveMovie();

        Pageable nextPage = PageRequest.of(0, 4, Sort.Direction.ASC, "movieId");

        nextPage = verifyPages(nextPage, "[1, 2, 3, 4]", true);
        nextPage = verifyPages(nextPage, "[5, 6, 7, 8]", true);
        verifyPages(nextPage, "[9, 10]", false);

    }

    private Pageable verifyPages(Pageable nextPage, String idsAsString, boolean hasNext) {
        Page<MovieEntity> moviePage = movieRepository.findAll(nextPage);
        assertEquals(hasNext, moviePage.hasNext());

        String ids = moviePage.get().map(MovieEntity::getMovieId).collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
        assertEquals(idsAsString, ids);
        return nextPage.next();
    }

    private void bulkSaveMovie() {
        movieRepository.deleteAll();

        List<MovieEntity> movies = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                .mapToObj(i -> MovieEntity.builder()
                        .movieId(i)
                        .title("Movie nr: " + i)
                        .build())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        movieRepository.saveAll(movies);
    }


    private void assertEqualsMovie(MovieEntity expected, MovieEntity actual) {
        assertAll("Executing assertEqualsMovie(..)", () -> {
            assertEquals(expected.getId(), actual.getId());
            assertEquals(expected.getVersion(), actual.getVersion());
            assertEquals(expected.getMovieId(), actual.getMovieId());
            assertEquals(expected.getTitle(), actual.getTitle());
            assertEquals(expected.getAddress(), actual.getAddress());
            assertEquals(expected.getGenre(), actual.getGenre());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You code is working fine.add H2 database and populate it with a movie. Your test is trying to find a movie with id 1 which does not exist hence it throws exception. at this line `.orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("No product found for productId: " + movieId));`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I am not using H2 but embedded mongo db. But still not resolved, I have no idea why this wont work because code looks fine form me..

Comment: you need to add `H2` database it will work. if you are not interested in adding an in-memory database then mock your `repository`.